# how to publish vs2010 web solution under framework 3.5 on iis?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, iis

Iam using visual studio 2010. i have developed one web application. my iis application pool was set to 3.5 only. when i deployed my app on iis it is showing target framework=4.0 error.

can any one tell me how to deploy my visual studio 2010 web project to run under dotnet framework 3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open project files (.sln and .csproj) files in notepad and find the following lines(1st line) and replace with second line, you will convert your application to vs2008 successfully

TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0" 
TargetFramework = "3.5"

Visual Studio 2010

Visual Studio 2008

Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00 
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00

10.0.20506 
9.0.30729

\VisualStudio\v10.0\ 
\VisualStudio\v9.0\

if u not find some lines dont worry , leave it

after changes, you may get a error from web.config from tag
 
remove this tag entirely, and also you may get config section errors like register components in web.config remove those tags also, and compile your code and run(what ever errors you may get from web.config remove them appropriately).